# SLinkedList and Node in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

To start with, yes, this is for an assignment in class, but my lack of understanding on how it operates is higher than I want it to be.

We were given 3 classes, they are the following:

SLinkedList.java

```
package chapter3.linkedList;

public class SLinkedList<V> {
    // instance variables.  Add the tail reference.
    protected Node<V> head, tail;
    protected long size;

    // methods, empty list constructor first
    public SLinkedList () {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }  // end constructor of a SLinkedList

    // method to add nodes to the list.  Storage space for the node
    // is already allocated in the calling method
    public void addFirst (Node<V> node) {
        // set the tail only if this is the very first node
        if (tail == null)
            tail = node;
        node.setNext (head);    // make next of the new node refer to the head
        head = node;            // give head a new value

        // change our size
        size++;
    }  // end method addFirst

    // addAfter - add new node after current node, checking to see if we are at the tail
    public void addAfter (Node<V>currentNode, Node<V>newNode) {
        if (currentNode == tail)
            tail = newNode;
        newNode.setNext (currentNode.getNext ());
        currentNode.setNext (newNode);

        // change our size
        size++;
    }  // end method addAfter

    // addLast - add new node after the tail node.  Adapted from Code Fragment 3.15, p. 118.
    // Mike Qualls
    public void addLast (Node<V> node) {
        node.setNext (null);
        tail.setNext (node);
        tail = node;
        size++;     
    }  // end method addLast

    // methods to remove nodes from the list.  (Unfortunately, with a single linked list
    // there is no way to remove last.  Need a previous reference to do that.  (See
    // Double Linked Lists and the code below.)
    public Node<V> removeFirst () {
        if (head == null)
            System.err.println("Error:  Attempt to remove from an empty list");

        // save the one to return
        Node<V> temp = head;

        // do reference manipulation
        head = head.getNext ();
        temp.setNext(null);
        size--;

        return temp;

    }  // end method removeFirst

    // remove the node at the end of the list.  tail refers to this node, but
    // since the list is single linked, there is no way to refer to the node
    // before the tail node.  Need to traverse the list.
    public Node<V> removeLast () {
        // // declare local variables/objects
        Node<V> nodeBefore;
        Node<V> nodeToRemove;

        // make sure we have something to remove
        if (size == 0)
            System.err.println("Error:  Attempt to remove fron an empty list");

        // traverse through the list, getting a reference to the node before
        // the trailer.  Since there is no previous reference.
        nodeBefore = getFirst ();

        // potential error  ??  See an analysis and drawing that indicates the number of iterations
        // 9/21/10.  size - 2 to account for the head and tail nodes.  We want to refer to the one before the
        // tail.
        for (int count = 0; count < size - 2; count++)
            nodeBefore = nodeBefore.getNext ();

        // save the last node
        nodeToRemove = tail;

        // now, do the pointer manipulation
        nodeBefore.setNext (null);
        tail = nodeBefore;
        size--;

        return nodeToRemove;

    }  // end method removeLast

    // method remove.  Remove a known node from the list.  No need to search or return a value.  This method
    // makes use of a 'before' reference in order to allow list manipulation.
    public void remove (Node<V> nodeToRemove) {
        // declare local variables/references
        Node<V> nodeBefore, currentNode;

        // make sure we have something to remove
        if (size == 0)
            System.err.println("Error:  Attempt to remove fron an empty list");

        // starting at the beginning check for removal
        currentNode = getFirst ();
        if (currentNode == nodeToRemove)
            removeFirst ();
        currentNode = getLast ();
        if (currentNode == nodeToRemove)
            removeLast ();

        // we've already check two nodes, check the rest
        if (size - 2 > 0) {
            nodeBefore = getFirst ();
            currentNode = getFirst ().getNext ();
            for (int count = 0; count < size - 2; count++) {
                if (currentNode == nodeToRemove) {
                    // remove current node
                    nodeBefore.setNext (currentNode.getNext ());
                    size--;
                    break;
                }  // end if node found

                // change references
                nodeBefore = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.getNext ();
            }  // end loop to process elements
        }  // end if size - 2 > 0

    }  // end method remove

    // the gets to return the head and/or tail nodes and size of the list
    public Node<V> getFirst () { return head; }
    public Node<V> getLast () { return tail; }  
    public long getSize () { return size; }

}  // end class SLinkedList
```

Node.java

package chapter3.linkedList;

```
public class Node<V> {
    // instance variables
    private V element;
    private Node<V> next;

    // methods, constructor first
    public Node () {
        this (null, null);      // call the constructor with two args
    }  // end no argument constructor
    public Node (V element, Node<V> next) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
    }  // end constructor with arguments

    // set/get methods
    public V getElement () { return element; }
    public Node<V> getNext () { return next; }
    public void setElement (V element) { this.element = element; }
    public void setNext (Node<V> next) { this.next = next; }

}  // end class Node
```

and GameEntry.java

```
package Project_1;

public class GameEntry 
{
    protected String name;  // name of the person earning this score
    protected int score;    // the score value
    /** Constructor to create a game entry */
    public GameEntry(String name, int score) 
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.score = score;
    }
    /** Retrieves the name field */
    public String getName() 
    { 
        return name; 
    }
    /** Retrieves the score field */
    public int getScore() 
    { 
        return score; 
    }
    /** Returns a string representation of this entry */
    public String toString() 
    { 
      return "(" + name + ", " + score + ")"; 
    }

}
```

I've spent the past 3 hours listening to his lecture, reading through the text (Data Structures and Algorithms 5th Edition), and looking through internet forums and youtube videos, but I can't seem to grasp any understanding of how to utilize the node/slinkedlist class.

The object of the assignment is "Write a class that maintains the top 10 scores or a game application, implementing the add and remove methods, but using a single linked list instead of an array.

I don't want someone to do this for me, but I do want to know how to make the linked list.  I know these are NOT that hard, but doing them with this code he's given has become painfully difficult, any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

My main function: ScoresTest.java

```
package Project_1;

public class ScoresTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
          GameEntry entry;
          Scores highScores = new Scores();     
          entry = new GameEntry("Anna", 600);       
          highScores.add(entry);
          entry = new GameEntry("Paul", 720);
          highScores.add(entry); 
          System.out.println("The Original High Scores");
          System.out.println(highScores);

          entry = new GameEntry("Jill", 1150);
          highScores.add(entry);
          System.out.println("Scores after adding Jill");
          System.out.println(highScores);
    }

}
```

This is for the most part exactly how it should end up looking, but it's everything that makes this work that's throwing me off...well...everything dealing with the 3 classes mentioned above, I could do this if they weren't a factor without too much of an issue, they are what's causing my blank.

Comment: is it instantiating the linkedlist class given that you're having trouble with?

Comment: It's all of it, apparently in the scores driver we are to create we have to call node, gameentry, and slinkedlist to make it work, and I'm just not sure how to do this.  I'm sure it can't be that hard, but for some reason I just can't figure it.

Comment: You understand the concept of a main method, and Generics or is this your first java class?  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Intermediate Java, but I haven't been doing java for quite some time.  We're using eclipse and I understand the concept of main method, I'm adding my main method as you read this.

Comment: OK i see your edit now, you are going to have to get the GameEntry's onto the LL that's what you want to your LL to store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a skeleton, without doing much for you this at least talks you through what you have so far in the comments above:

```
public class ScoreDriver
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SLinkedList<GameEntry> sll = new SlinkedList<GameEntry>();
  }
}
```

Once you have this in eclipse, auto-complete will take you pretty far.  Instantiating the linked list class with generics could be odd if you've never seen them before. Focus, on SLinkedList though it has a lot of utility for what you want to do, don't worry about Node too much upfront.

Comment: That is a huge help, couldn't for the life of me figure out how to make that work.  I've not seen <> used before (I had this teacher for intro to java, I have all of my code used and that he used, none of it ever used those brackets), so that may be what is throwing me off a bit...will respond as this is the answer if I can avoid any more hiccups, thank you though for this assistance!

Comment: Good luck, if you're going to be doing more of this you should take a look at a java generics tutorial.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for that, makes perfect sense and everything worked out great!